# Exclude thumb folder from url RewriteRule with regular expression

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, watermark

```
    RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.jpg$ watermark.php?image=$1\.jpg [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.gif$ watermark.php?image=$1\.gif [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.png$ watermark.php?image=$1\.png [L]
 RewriteRule ^(.+)\.bmp$ watermark.php?image=$1\.bmp [L]
```

I want to exclude thumbnails from applying watermark:

http:// ... /gallery/photos/4db83e206ae00/4db83e559209e.jpg **YES!**

http:// ... /gallery/photos/4db83e206ae00/thumb/4db83e559209e.jpg **NO!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
RewriteCond $1 !/thumb/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp)$ watermark.php?image=$0 [L]
```